# Python trouble using classes to create a "directory" of user inputed information

Tags: python, class, input, authentication

I am very new at coding with classes so any help would be appreciated. So I am trying to prompt a user for basic information like name, username, and password. Then I would like to save a class object named after the username inputted with all of the other attributes inputted. I appended each of these attributes to a list to call on them easier late. However, I keep getting an error that python has not attribute named "z".

```
class Login:
  usernames = []
  passwords = []
  firsts = []
  lasts = []

  def __init__(self, first, last, username, password):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    Login.usernames.append(self.username)
    Login.passwords.append(self.password)
    Login.firsts.append(self.first)
    Login.lasts.append(self.last)

  def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

x = input('What is your first name? ')
y = input('What is your last name? ')
z = input('What do you want your username to be?')
w = input('What do you want your password to be? ')
z = Login(x , y, z, w)

print(Login.z)
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you mean `print(z.fullname())`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the `z` member of the `Login` class, but it does not exist, which is why you get the error. It looks like you're trying to use the `z` variable in the global scope, in which case you wouldn't need to prefix it with `Login`. You can use `z.methodname()` to call the method you want. For instance, if you wanted to print `z`'s full name, do this:

```
print(z.fullname())
```

See [here](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) for more information on variable scoping.